# How to determine lower bound pixel value of a gray image using Chebyshev inequality in python-opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, math, statistics, gaussian

I have a theoretical background in probability but I want to implement Chebyshev inequality on any gray image for a better binarization or segmentation. Having known the distribution of the gray image it is possible to find the value k where pixels do not differ more than a certain value from the mean.
My questions are as follows:

1. How to implement Chebyshev's inequality in python-OpenCV?
2. Is There any public codes that I can implement and hedge around my parameters based on the image statistics?
   I have seen an implementation of 1D data but it is not clearly explained so it is not easy to follow when implementing 2D and 3D refer [this one](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/illustration-with-python-chebyshevs-inequality-b34be151c547) and [this](https://gist.github.com/chaipi-chaya/9eb72978dbbfd7fa4057b493cf6a32e7).
   NB: The nature of my grayscale image is mixed gaussian.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions